# Can you help me to find infinite sum?

Tags: analysis

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{\lfloor 2^n x\rfloor}}{2^n}$$

find  the  series  for  $0\leqslant x\lt 1$.  What  can  we  say  about  $x\geqslant 1$?

Comment: What do you have inside the floor function?

Comment: ok.  (2^n)*x  in  the  floor  function

Answer (score 3):

If $0\leq x<1$, write $x$ in its binary expansion. Note that $\lfloor2^nx\rfloor$ returns the $n$th binary floating digit (up to a multiple of $2$). For example $\lfloor 2^4\cdot\frac13\rfloor$ is odd, which means the $4$th digit of $\frac13$ written in binary is $1$. Indeed, $\frac13=0.01010101\ldots_2$.

To see why this is true in general, write $x=(0.b_1b_2b_3\ldots)_2$, then $2^nx=(b_1b_2\cdots b_n.b_{n+1}b_{n+2}\ldots)_2$, where $(b_1\cdots b_{n-1}0)_2$ is an even number.

Binary digits can only be $0$ or $1$. If the $n$th digit of $x$ is $0$, it will contribute a value of $\frac1{2^n}$ to the sum. If that digit is $1$, it will contribute $\frac{-1}{2^n}$.

So, if we substract $1=\frac12+\frac14+\frac18+\cdots$ from our sum, we would obtain $-2x$ because the impact of $0$-digits is compensated and the impact of $1$-digits is doubled.

Therefore, the sum would result in $1-2x$.

Now try to see what happens if $x\geq1$: what is $\lfloor 2^nx\rfloor$ if $1\leq x=1+y$?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**. How does $\lfloor 2^nx \rfloor$ being even relate to the binary representation of $x$?